# spring Integration take back up file after sftp to remote server

Tags: spring, integration, adapter, sftp, outbound

I am using outbound channel adapter for sftp the files to some other location... after the sftp , I want to take the back up  to a different location... Just wondering how to do the same ? Is it possible to redirect it to some other channel ?

My sftp config is below.

```
<integ-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter"
                session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" `enter code here`
                channel="sftp-push" auto-create-directory="true" 
                charset="UTF-8"
                remote-directory-expression="headers['remotedir']"   />
```